# QGIS how to save loaded min/max values for raster layers?

Tags: qgis, raster

I am working with many layers.  Each time I open my saved project, I must reload the min/max (properties/style) values.  Is there a way to turn off the default 2% cut?

Answer (score 3):

You can try changing it in `Settings > Options | Rendering (tab)`

There is a section in the `Rendering` tab called `Rasters`.

You can change either the `Contrast Enhancement(s)` to "Stretch to MinMax"

Or the `Limits to "Minimum / maximum"` and the `Cumulative pixel count cut limits` to 0% and 100% respectively.

If this doesn't work, consider adding a bug report or feature request at https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues